# Effective Way to Count Distance on a Combination Lock

Tags: locking, combinations, formula

I have a problem where I have to find the distance, or ticks, from one location on a lock to the other.  For example, assuming a combination lock with numbers 0 - 39, I want to move from 38 to 10, and get 12, which is the number of ticks it takes to get from 38 to 10.  This can be set up as (38 + x) mod 40 = 10, except that there isn't any way to isolate the x because of the modulus operation.  Can anyone think of a way to create a simple formula to find that there are 12 ticks between 38 and 10.  I know how to do it using conditional branching, but I would prefer to use a formula if possible.

Comment: I have a gut feeling you can do this by treating the lock like a unit circle and using trig functions, though I'm still working out exactly _how_...

Comment: Huh.  That'd be cool if it works out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases.

1. A distance "within range"
2. A distance "overflow"

You need to calculate both and select the minimum.

```
min((to-from) mod 40, (from-to) mod 40)
```

Update: The previous version did not work in every case (e.g. from 1 to 25). The current version always returns the cheapest amount of ticks but without a direction (unsigned).

Comment: @Jonners Write it?  I did specify no branching, but I don't think I can get away without using it.  The min function is pretty easy to write.

Comment: Would it make sense that if I were to go the other way, to take the max of the two?